# HTML text inputs not returning proper value

Tags: php, mysql

I used to be program in .Net so PHP with MySQL is very new for me.
I wanted to have same form for displaying and updating the DB, with work fine. I dont have issues with that, but after the save happens, the text inputs retains old value.

My HTML side

```
  <select class="form-control" name="form1">
    
    <option selected="selected">
      <?php echo htmlspecialchars($GLO_variable1); ?>
    </option>
    <option value="option1">option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">option 2</option>
  </select>

<input class="btn btn-primary"  type="submit" name="updaterecord" value="Update Summary">
```

I wanted the options to to reflect current record on the DB, which works fine when viewing/getting the record from DB.

```
<?php

function GetRecord(){

  require 'conn.php';

  if(!session_id()) session_start();
  $globalinc = $_SESSION["globalinc"];

  if(isset($globalinc)){
    $sqlget="SELECT * FROM t_summary WHERE SNOW_INC= '". $globalinc ."'";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlget);
    $getrecordarray = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    $GLOBALS['GLO_PRIORITY'] = $getrecordarray['PRIORITY'];
    $GLOBALS['GLO_INC_STATEMENT'] = $getrecordarray['INC_STATEMENT'];

    mysqli_free_result($result);
    mysqli_close($conn);
  }
}

?>
```

The above example sets data from MySQL to text input and text area in HTML. I called GetRecord() at the beginning of body with

```
<body>

  <?php GetRecord();  ?>

</body>
```

Then I try to make changes to the form and update it with following.

```
<?php

function UpdateRecord(){

  require 'conn.php';

  $snowinc = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["SNOW_INC"]);
  $incstatement = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["INC_STATEMENT"]);
  $priority = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["PRIORITY"]);

  $sql = "REPLACE INTO t_summary (SNOW_INC, INC_STATEMENT, PRIORITY)
  VALUES ('$snowinc', '$incstatement', '$priority')";

  if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

    echo "<br>";
    echo "Incident Summary updated successfully.";
    echo "<br>";

  } else {

    echo "<br>";
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    echo "<br>";
  }

  $conn->close();
  
}

if(array_key_exists('SNOW_INC',$_POST)){
    UpdateRecord();
}

?>
```

Well, his also works well updating the data to DB, but problem happens after I saw a data.

For example, if value in DB shows `option 1` then when I view the page it shows `option 1`, all good. When I change the value to `option 2` and save, the value is updated in DB but remained the same in HTML. Obviously if I reload the page, it shows `option 2` but I'm trying to avoid that.

Any idea to fix this will be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.
And I know I missed lots of other stuff here. Please ask questions if you want to know more info to fix this.

Thanks again!!

Edit : I have uploaded the site so you can look at the issue better

Instruction :

1. Go to https://www.mydevplace.xyz/alpha/ and create do a search of any string. It will say record not found and prompt you to create one.
2. Create a record. Should be self explanatory. Make sure to click Update Incident record. You should get a green confirmation saying Incident Summary updated successfully.
3. Now on the same page, edit the values to a different strings/records and click the same button. The values is returning to previous value. Thats my problem. If you keep clicking the button, you would see what I mean.

EDIT 2 : I implemented AJAX to update my records and only GetUpdate on first load of the page. All is working well now.

Thanks to all who helped me with this.

Comment: If you are only starting with PHP then please do not learn mysqli. You should learn PDO instead. It is much easier

Comment: Just heard of PDO. Might adjust my code accordingly but I think my issue would persists nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

Change option value from option1 to option2

```
<option value="option1">option 2</option>
```

To

```
<option value="option2">option 2</option>
```

Although you have not shared your html, It will be difficult to estimate error.
However I found the below issue with you php codes.

```
function GetRecord(){
  global $getrecordarray;
..
..
..

}
```

You forgot to define the $getrecordarray as global.

Comment: Ok, I did a typo there. It was already like you you suggested.

Comment: Nope, it did not.

Comment: Ok, I did that too, it still doesnt work. I now uploaded my work so you can see the issue better. Look at my edited question above.